# Rhino: load multiple scripts in command line with -e 'load([...])' option

Tags: rhino

I'm trying to run multiple scripts with Rhino shell using the command:

```
java org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main -e 'load(["script_a.js", "script_b.js"])'
```

And here is the error:

```
js: Couldn't read source file "script_a.js,script_b.js: script_a.js,script_b.js (No such file or directory)".
```

It looks like Rhino receives 2 script names as a single string because of Bash interpreter. As far as I know, special characters enclosed in the single quotes should not be interpreted.
Tried a lot of different combinations with no luck. What I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure you know about this, but still... You may consider to use:

java org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main -e 'load("script_a.js");load("script_b.js");'

Or reload 'load' function that is not recommended. Or something like that:
[Resolving modules using require.js and Java/Rhino](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11074836/resolving-modules-using-require-js-and-java-rhino)

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: "js/app"
});

require (["a", "b"], function(a,  b) {
    print('modules loaded');
});
```

Comment: `java org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main -e 'load("script_a.js");load("script_b.js");'` works. Thank you!